# Position Unity UGUI ScrollRect Content Position from Script

Tags: unity

I have a [map in my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wYi7.png) the user can interact with. I am using Unity UGUI `ScrollRect` to let the user move the map on the screen. Only one area of the map is visible at a time and you can scroll it to get to the desired level (just like in King games). The content of this map system is an `Image` and level buttons which are all children of the map image.

I want my `ScrollRect` to point to the current active level when the map loads. For example, if I am on level 30 then on loading the map level the content of the `ScrollRect` should be on the portion of the map where level 30 is.

I can't find anything regarding managing `ScrollRect`'s content position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the scrolling position parameters for [ScrollRect](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.html)

- [Horizontal Normalized Position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-horizontalNormalizedPosition.html)
- [Vertical Normalized Position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html)

You would need to find your level marker's position in it's parent (the ScrollRect) and then convert it to a normalized position (divide position by the parents width/height). From there you can set the horizontal and vertical normalized position to the desired values.